# XSD with a variable value for min-max Occurrence in xs:sequence?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am trying to create an XSD of following type

```
<xs:element name="Command">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="NumberofArgument" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
        <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Argument" minOccurs=variable>
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="argumentName" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="argumentType" type="argumentType"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>          
    </xs:complexType>   
</xs:element>
```

So whatever XML I create I will first define the attribute "NumberOfArguments" and then I will use to validate the actual number of arguments for the given command.

```
<Command CommandName="String" number="1">
    <Argument argumentName="String" argumentType="defined"/>
</Command>
```

So my question is Is it possible to acheive this, if not whats the other way to do this.

Comment: From what I know this is not possible by simply validating the schema. You would have to process this 'after the fact' using the language of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

The Saxon schema processor has an experimental extension that allows you to declare parameters which can be referenced in XSD 1.1 assertions. But there's nothing in the standard language to allow it.

An approach that might work for you is to define the minOccurs as an XML entity reference

```
minOccurs="&min;"
```

and then define the expansion of the entity in an external file, which you could set up prior to the validation episode.

Comment: Thanks, But Can you provide me reference links to this processor So that I can read more about this.